# how to navigate the desire view controller after successful login of Facebook?

Tags: objective-c

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];

loginButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:loginButton];

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    NSLog(@"the user is lopgged in ");
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondid"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
    // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
    loginButton.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:loginButton];


}}
```

I am using the above code for Facebook login here the Facebook login is working fine but i want to navigate the desire view controller after the successful login of Facebook but this above code navigate to the same page but when i am running at second time it will navigate to another view controller but in first time it will come back to home viewcontroller.for example i have to login the Facebook in one view controller  and have to logout on another view controller.

Comment: Do you want to close current viewcontroller and open another view controller?

Comment: thanks for your reply .yes i need the same

Comment: Make presenting viewController. Than dismiss current viewcontroller and on its compeletion block present new viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController *presentViewController = self.presentingViewController;
```

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

```
SeconViewController *controller = [[SeconViewController alloc]init];//Initialize your viewcontroller

UINavigationController *navCtrlr = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:controller];
[presentViewController presentViewController:navCtrlr animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}];

Comment: my problem is at first running it's not working while running at second time the page will navigate  to another viewcontroller